# Jenkins scm polling doesn't detect changes if we use parameter(environment variable) in branch field

Tags: jenkins, polling

Jenkins scm polling doesn't detect changes if we use parameter(environment variable) in branch field. Note that the environment variable is coming from the pipeline config and the job which does scm polling is part of the pipeline.

I'm using git plugin  git-2.5.0-beta5

Answer (score 1):

I spent 1.5 weeks on the same issue. There two ways for (in fact, only one) to build multibranch projects:

- [deprecated](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin) plugin
- Multibranch pipeline job type

I hope this answer will save a couple of hours to next researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Its a issue with Jenkins. The parameters are not set during polling.
try this WA.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33719?focusedCommentId=251585&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-251585